# Visitor method for all labels

Tags: java, antlr4

I have a parser rule with alternative labels.
I would like to implement a visitor method for when any of the labels are well visited:

```
someRule
    :    'a' #aLabel
    |    'b' #bLabel
    |    'c' #cLabel
    ;
```

And I need some method like this:

```
T visitSomeRule(SomeRuleContext ctx)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With labels like yours you'll end up with something like:

```
override VisitAlabel(aLabelRuleContext) {....}
override VisitBlabel(bLabelRuleContext) {....}
override VisitClabel(cLabelRuleContext) {....}
```

However, adding the alternative labels causes ANTLR4 to NOT generate the generic context class `SomeRuleContext` in your example above.  It's not possible to have a mix of both.  One or the other.  If you want access to `SomeRuleContext` then you must remove the labels and check for the alternative contexts inside the handler for `SomeRuleContext.`

My source: experience with this and *The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference* by Terence Parr, page 120.

Comment: Maybe could I override the visit method and check the type of the argument? That's seem like a hacky way, though.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to in my answer.  If you read Terence Parr's book about the alternative labels, it's clear that this feature was added to give "more precise" contexts through more focused subclassing.  And I've found that I prefer the use of labels for most of my work.  But if you really need that higher-level context, you can certainly iterate through its Children, examine their types, and act on them individually.  It's possible, and I've done it. Until I learned about the alternative labels.  ;)